# Google Sheets FORMULATEXT not updating

Tags: google-sheets

So FORMULATEXT is not updating when the referenced objects are changed even tho the formula that it's turning to text has changed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V00i3XlEx5Q2Xp0QZevS5o2pdpU2QNNNX5d8bkHtn3U/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Before Change]

[image: After Inserting a column]

Any other ways to achieve this or a way to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. To me, it does update the value. Do you still experience it?

Comment: Same here - if i move (or cut and paste) column G to column H, B2 and B3 both change dynamically, from =G:G>0 to =H:H>0.  How are you "moving the cells from G to H?  And if you aren't moving them, then the formulae shouldn't change...  Or am I missing the issue you're describing?

Comment: insert a column to the left

Comment: I see it now.  Does look like a bug...

Comment: Yes, I does look like a bug. I recommend you to report it from `Help > Report a problem`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's the smartest solution, but this will work, assuming your reference object columns moves between Column E to N, you can edit the formula per your requirement

```
=(regexextract(ADDRESS(row(),column(index(E1:N1,match(sum(E1:N1),E1:N1,0)))),"[A-z]"))&":"&(regexextract(ADDRESS(row(),column(index(E1:N1,match(sum(E1:N1),E1:N1,0)))),"[A-z]"))>0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not gonna do full justice as I will could potentially move further than those columns, wouldn't want to risk it breaking. Thank you for your help tho!

Comment: Not gonna do full justice as I will could potentially move further than those columns, wouldn't want to risk it breaking. Thank you for your help tho!

Comment: you can extend the column range by editing the formula

Answer (score -1):

set calculation to:

[image]

and try:

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)&IFERROR(NOW()/0)
```

[image]

Comment: This not worked for me